# How static library in c++ work with name mangle?

Tags: c++, name-mangling

I ask this for understanding, In c there is no name mangling but c++ has. How this works for example say I have following files

- exlib.hpp header file
- exlib.cpp function implemented file
- exapp.cpp main function using exlib

File exlib.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef EXLIB
#define EXLIB

#include <iostream>

int sum(int, int);
int sum(int, int, int);
int sum(int, int, int, int);

#endif
```

File exlib.cpp

```cpp
#include "exlib.hpp"

int sum(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "In sum(int, int)" << std::endl;
    return a + b;
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << "In sum(int, int, int)" << std::endl;
    return a + b + c;
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    std::cout << "In sum(int, int, int, int)" << std::endl;
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

File exapp.cpp

```cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "exlib.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum(1, 1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum(2, 2, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum(3, 3, 3, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

Compile

```sh
$ g++ -c exlib.cpp
$ g++ exapp.cpp exlib.o -o exapp
$ ./exapp
```

sum in exlib.o are name mangled right ?

output:

```sh
Sum = In sum(int, int)
2
Sum = In sum(int, int, int)
6
Sum = In sum(int, int, int, int)
12
```

1. How sum correctly called after name mangle in main ?, There is any rules for name mangling that same name is replaced in main or How they identify?
2. All programming language mangle name in same way ?

Thanks.

Comment: The name mangling is applied by the compiler because linkers do not support polymorphy -> each distinct symbol has to have a unique name. That's independent of static vs. dynamic linking. Though, name mangling is not standardized for C++ in general, each compiler will have it's unique reproducible way to do this. Hence, if `exapp.cpp` will `#include <exlib.hpp>` it will mangle the names in the same way like it was done for `exlib.cpp`. Hence, it will get the exact symbol names the linker need for proper linking.

Comment: In my previous comment, I ignored the fact that there exist [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s which require a unique name mangling. However, ABIs are less encompassing standards than the C++ standard in general.

Comment: Thanks for reply, So if i compile it in g++,  i can not use that exlib.o in other compiler ?

Comment: And i used static linking because i did't used dynamic linking before.

Comment: g++ and clang share an ABI if I remember right. But using a g++ library with MSVC... This doesn't work except that g++ provides a compatibility mode for MSVC. (I'm not quite sure whether MingGW or cygwin offer such feature.) What I'm sure: Even distinct versions of MSVC++ doesn't produce compatible binary code - a fact which caused that we  use DLLs with C APIs in the specific case that the library compiler and the application compiler are not necessarily the same. (E.g. for plug-ins)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :-), can you change the comment to answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While C++ offers [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) (i.e. different things can be named equal in the same scope by using other features for distinguishing them), this is not supported by linkers (neither in statical nor dynamical linking). So, C++ compilers uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). (The other features are used to decorate the original identifier to produce a unique name.)

A C++ compiler compiles each C++ file (aka. [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) on its own. Hence, it is obvious that the name mangling has to be done in a unique, reproducible way by this compiler. I.e. the same declaration has to be mapped to the same symbol always.
Otherwise, it would be impossible for the linker to resolve symbols that were declared (only) in one file and defined in another.

However, there isn't a general name-mangling standard (e.g. as part of the C++ standard).

So, even on the same platform, the binary codes produced by two different compilers may be incompatible due to different name-mangling (as well as other details).
(For [MS Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Compatibility), this makes even binaries from distinct versions incompatible.)

To overcome this, there exist [Application Binary Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABIs) for certain platforms (e.g. Linux).
One detail of an ABI is a standardized name-mangling.